# Prevent Sphinx from executing the module

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to do python documentation generation with Sphinx. The problem is that sphinx-build ends up executing the module/evaluating anything in global scope. Is there a reason it does this? And does anyone know of a flag that can be set to disable this?

It seems like Sphinx is trying to do code-coverage or something equivalent, which is definitely not what I want it doing. Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but a particular set of modules are very specific to an environment.

Comment: Yes it's normal the modules are imported by sphinx when autodoc. It has to do that in order to retrieve the docstrings, classes and functions info, etc. Could you provide a little bit more info? How does it stop? What is the message? etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sphinx evaluates everything in the global scope because the autodoc plugin imports modules, and importing a module evaluates everything in the global scope.

To stop this, either:

- Disable the autodoc plugin (search for `autodoc` in the sphinx config file), or
- Guard the code you don't want executed with something like `if __name__ == "__main__": do_stuff()`

Comment: Ah -- yes, that conveniently works, since the few globals I do have are only relevant to the module if it is being run as a script. I can place them inside that statement. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to use autodoc without importing the module? For example if we only need autodoc to read/parse docstring (not containing any tests or fancy code interpretation of any kind, just plain text). That looks a bit overkill to import all our project dependencies to read docstrings.

Comment: I think that executing the code just to get docstrings is a very bad design, it converts buildtime into runtime. They could just parse the code and extract docstrings like any other code documentation generator in the known universe.